# Vim can't scroll in iTerm2

Tags: vim, iterm2

My vim can't scroll in iTerm2 even `set mouse=a` has added in `.vimrc` file.

Within tmux, however, vim's scroll function works correctly.

What's wrong with my vim?

Comment: how do you scroll? mouse? arrow keys? or `hjkl`? or `ctrl+?`?

Comment: Please run `vim --version` from the command-line, or in Vim, enter :version and provide output.

Comment: On a side note, using the mouse to scroll is an antipattern in both Vim and tmux, and nullifies the advantages of using such tools.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Recent versions of vim support the "SGR" protocol, you can add code bellow to your .vimrc:

```
set mouse=a
if has("mouse_sgr")
    set ttymouse=sgr
else
    set ttymouse=xterm2
end
```

Comment: unfortunately this make text selection with mouse different (highlights with solid dark color).. any way to fix that?

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue, and Valery's answer did not work for me. What did work is checking the "Enable mouse reporting" box under Profiles > Terminal in the iTerm preferences.

Comment: That did the trick for me, thanks 

Comment: Thanks! This worked. It was driving me insane.

Comment: It is likely that you can accidentally disable this which does break scrolling in Vim